# System of Equations , Finding value of coefficient so equations are inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> > Question; Calculate a value for the coefficient $'a'$ of $x$ so that the solutions to the three equations are inconsistent. Demonstrate the resulting system of equations are then inconsistent:
> >     $$ x+2y+2z=6$$
> >     $$ x-y+z=-4$$
> >     $$  ax+y-9z=-1$$
> >
> > Cannot use matrix/matrics

---

What I have attempted:

Using the first 2 equations to eliminate $z$

$$ x+2y+2z=-6$$
$$ x-y+z=-4$$

Multiplying the second by $2$

$$ x+2y+2z=6$$
$$ 2x-2y+2z=-8$$

Subtracting both to get

$$ -x + 4y = 14 $$

$$ y = \frac{14}{4} + \frac{x}{4} $$

Again using the first 2 equations to eliminate y

$$ x+2y+2z=-6$$
$$ x-y+z=-4$$

Multiplying the second by $-2$

$$ x + 2y + 2z = -6 $$

$$ -2x + 2y - 2z = 8 $$

Subtracting

$$ 3x +  4z = -14 $$

$$ z = \frac{-14}{4} - \frac{3x}{4} $$

Subbing both $z$ and $y$ into $ax+y-9z=-1$

$$ ax + \frac{14}{4} + \frac{x}{4} -9(\frac{-14}{4} - \frac{3x}{4}) = -1 $$

$$ax + \frac{14}{4} + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{63}{2} + \frac{27x}{4} = -1  $$

$$ ax  + 7x = -36 $$

$$ x(a+7) = -36 $$

Now I am stuck, how do I find the value of a?

Comment: Just by looking at the last equality, if $a=-7$, you get $0=-36$ for any values of $x$.

Comment: If you take the determinant of the coefficient matrix you get $4(a+7)$ so the system is inconsistent for $a = -7$ and consistent for all other values of $a$

Comment: @GaussTheBauss well that was easier than expected!t thank you!

Comment: @dydxx You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a computer doing basic algebra. It is tedious to do it by hand.

[image]

Leting $a= \frac{-28}{4}$ will reduce the system to $0x+0y+0za=1$ and $0 \neq 1$

[image]